# How to add class to list view colum in webpart or hide column

Tags: 2010, web-part, jquery, css, xlv

This is Sharepoint 2010.

I have a list view webpart(calendar) with title and date.

I am using Jquery to filter dates shown (workaround for limitations in filtering on reoccurring event). I need to keep the date for Jquery, but since date shown is only today's, how do I hide it? (removing it from view doesn't work because then my jquery can't filter)

I was thinking I would convert to XSLT in SPD and add a class (to hide with CSS) to the TD for date, but when I convert and save in designer, whole page layout gets screwed up. (I was trying "customize xslt" option in SPD).

Final goal is a web part that lists "todays events" based off of a Calendar list that only has the event's title. I am open to any alternative suggestions to achieve this, but please understand I am still learning and custom coding something is not really an option.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view for the calendar list. Set the filter option in the view as follows:
[image]

When adding the list view webpart set the view as the newly created view with filter condition.This will display list of events for today.

Comment: This does not work. The built-in view filtering is unable to correctly filter on reoccurring events. Unfortunately, this is the exact limitation that I had originally mentioned.